# Error con función de alto nivel en R

Tags: r, funciones, programación-funcional

Leyendo un poco sobre funciones de alto nivel en R, me puse a experimentar con un pequeño código que es una adaptación del que viene aquí:

http://renkun-ken.github.io/blog/2014/03/15/a-brief-introduction-to-higher-order-functions-in-r.html

El código es:

```
multi <- function(x,y,z, fun) {
    suma <- function(x,y,z) {
    x+y+z
    }
    producto <- function(x,y,z) {
    x*y*z
    }
    return(eval(fun(x,y,z)))
}
```

Como puede verse, funciona bien para las dos operaciones indicadas

```
multi(21,3,2,suma)         #26
multi(21,3,2, producto)    #126
```

Sin embargo, cuando agrego una tercera, obtengo un error:

```
multi <- function(x,y,z, fun) {
    suma <- function(x,y,z) {
    x+y+z
    }
    producto <- function(x,y,z) {
        x*y*z
    }
    potencia <- function(x,y,z) {
    x^y^z
    }
    return(eval(fun(x,y,z)))
}


multi(1,3,2, potencia)
Error in eval(fun(x, y, z)) : objeto 'potencia' no encontrado
```

No logro entender cuál es la fuente del error, así que cualquier referencia o comentario me sería de mucha utilidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En cualquier caso la función debería darte un error, no importa la cantidad de funciones que definas dentro de `multi` si partes de un entorno prístino (donde no existan las funciones internas ya definidas) lo que deberías obtener es un error:

```
rm("suma") # me aseguro que no exista la función "suma" en el entorno actual

multi <- function(x,y,z, fun) {
    suma <- function(x,y,z) {
        x+y+z
    }
    return(eval(fun(x,y,z)))
}

multi(1,3,2,suma)

Error in eval(fun(x, y, z)) : objeto 'suma' no encontrado
```

Cuando haces `multi(1,3,2,suma)`, todavía estás en el entorno general, el objeto `suma` no existe, por lo que en definitiva les estas enviando nada a la función, si luego intentas usar el parámetro `fun` obtendrás el error.

De lo que mencionas, que con ciertas funciones hace lo que espera y con `potencia` no, entiendo que lo que te puede estar pasando es que ya tengas definidas por afuera de la función `multi` las funciones `suma` y `producto` pero no así `potencia`.

¿Esto significa que no puedes acceder a una función interna indicando cuál se quiere usar desde un parámetro? NO, el tema es que la orquestación debe ser algo distinta, lo que podrías hacer es pasar el nombre de la función como cadena y usar `do.call()` que permite construir dinamicamente una invocación a una función:

```
multi <- function(x,y,z, fun) {
    suma <- function(x,y,z) {
        x+y+z
    }
    producto <- function(x,y,z) {
        x*y*z
    }
    potencia <- function(x,y,z) {
        x^y^z
    }
    return(do.call(fun, list(x, y, z)))
}

multi(1,3,2,"suma")
multi(1,3,2,"producto")
multi(1,3,2,"potencia")
```

En este casos `do.call()` recibe una cadena como parámetro para el nombre de una función y una lista con el resto de los parámetros de dicha función. `do.call` ejecutará la función indicada en el entorno local de la función `multi`, donde si están tienes definidas `suma()`, `producto()` y `potencia()`

Comment: Siempre es un placer leer tus respuestas: claras, concisas e ilustrativas. ¡Muchas gracias!